# PHP Validation Duplicate data in database

Tags: php, html

I want `StudentNumber` field that has no duplicate data. For example if someone uses the student number `x` meaning the other user will not allowed to register `x` again. Then the  the validation says "User already exists."

How can I do that validation?

This is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$_POST['fn'])) {
        if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z\s-]+$/',$_POST['ln'])){
                if(preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i',$_POST['email'])){
                    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/',$_POST['c_number'])){
                        $fn=$_POST['fn'];
                        $ln=$_POST['ln'];
                        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
                        $address=$_POST['address'];
                        $email=$_POST['email'];
                        $c_number=$_POST['c_number'];
                        $s_number=$_POST['sn'];
                        $College=$POST['collage'];

                        mysql_query("insert into reg_member (firstname,lastname,address,gender,email,c_number,date,stunumber,collage)
                             values('$fn','$ln','$address','$gender','$email','$c_number',NOW(),'$s_number','$College')
                                ")or die(mysql_error());
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                             alert('Youre Successfully Register Thank You');
                            window.location="index.php";
                          </script>
                            <?php

                    }
                    else {
                        echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'invalid contact number\');</script>';
                    }

                }
                else {
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'invalid email\');</script>';
                }


        }
        else {
            echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'invalid last name\');</script>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'invalid first name\');</script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Stopped reading after third nested if. Consider make your code more readable

Comment: Basically I see no select query, so I guess you should check for this number before inserting, with a select query that points to it. But first, make it clean

Answer (score 0):

MySQL fields can have the attribute [UNIQUE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp). THis allows only unique entries - which is exactly what you want. Read up on it.

```
ALTER TABLE `reg_member` ADD UNIQUE(`stunumber`);
```

MySQL will give you an error when you try to insert a number that is already in the database.
You can check for that error with [mysql_error](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-error.php) and [mysql_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-errno.php)